# Can I add a Microsoft Account to my Windows Server Core? (WITHOUT domain nor domain controller)

Tags: windows, active-directory, user-accounts, windows-server-core

Can I use Microsoft accounts in my Windows Server Core virtual machines as we can do with Windows 10 without domain controller role or additional magic?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use Microsoft accounts to log in to Windows Server operating systems. Microsoft accounts can only be used to log in to client Windows (8 or later).